# Hide Scollbar of ScrollView for Xamarin MAC platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I want to hide the scollbar of ScollView in Xamarin.Forms
I made rendere in UWP and it is working perfect and the code is

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ScrollView> e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                ScrollView el = (ScrollView)this.Element;

                Control.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
                //Control.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }           
    }
```

But can not able to find the **OnElementChanged** event for **MAC platform**

**So kindly guide me how to hide scollbar of ScollView for MAC**

A single guidance can lead to me a solution. Thanks is advance

Comment: Not that it will help you now, but this will be possible with default Forms in v4.0: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/3897 maybe it is already in the pre-release package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSScrollView: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview?language=objc

```
scrollView.HasVerticalScroller = false;
scrollView.HasHorizontalScroller = false;
```

Note: One of the issues within Cocoa/AppKit and mixing any CoreAnimation the scroll bars tend to flash... This has been radr'd for a long time so I doubt Apple will fix it as the future will be a UIKit "replacement". So if you are not animating the NSScrollView within its owning container, you *should not* have any problem, otherwise creating a custom NSView control might be the only way to go (that is what I have done). And thus Xamarin.Forms 4.0 does suffers from this issue.